# How to store GPS data from the arduino to a remote server using the ESP32 NodeMCU

Tags: arduino, gps, microcontroller, esp32

I'm currently working on a project for my senior design class this involves storing the longitude and latitude coordinates retrieved from a GPS module through an Arduino into a server. I am able to get the coordinates successfully and I've already established a link between the ESP32 and a firebase database, however I have no clue now transfer this data from the Arduino to the ESP32 and was wondering if anyone could guide or point me towards the right direction on how to do this? Would this even be possible? If not, what would be any good alternatives on approaching this situation? I'm very new at this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Arduino and NodeMCU appear to support I2C. You could wire them together and use that protocol to send information.

https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev-esp32/en/modules/i2c/
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire

Comment: Thanks! I looked into I2C and it looks like this is exactly what I need :)